User registration emails not being received
Our user registration forms are not being sent.  Some users do receive them but others not.
I have checked the DKIM and SPF records and they are set up.
I am using PHP Mailer.
On CMD I did nslookup -q=txt theproductnumber.com
And I see this:
Non-authoritative answer:
theproductnumber.com    text =

    "v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all" theproductnumber.com    text =

    "v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=none; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400" theproductnumber.com    text =

    "v=verifydomain MS=3303698"


Update
I'm aware SMTP is a better solution, but I always struggle to get it to work.  I'm using Office 365 for email.
Following this advice led me to the below information
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_debug_SMTP_mail_in_Joomla_4#:~:text=Go%20to%20Home%20Dashboard%20%E2%86%92%20System%20%E2%86%92%20Global%20Configuration%20%E2%86%92,Set%20Error%20Reporting%20to%20Maximum.
I now see that the tenant has SMTP turned off and have requested that to be turned on.
#Date: 2024-09-26 12:37:02 UTC
#Software: Joomla! 4.4.8 Stable [ Pamoja ] 27-August-2024 16:00 GMT

#Fields: datetime   priority clientip   category    message
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: opened
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "220 LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 26 Sep 2024 12:37:01 +0000 [08DCDDB9DCAC043D]"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 26 Sep 2024 12:37:01 +0000 [08DCDDB9DCAC043D]

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.theproductnumber.com

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.theproductnumber.com

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO2P265CA0098.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Requested auth method not available: 
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth method selected: LOGIN
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: aW5mb0B0aGVwcm9kdWN0bnVtYmVyLmNvbQ==

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6

2024-09-26T12:37:02+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: VzNsbDYyNjYwIyE/

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0098.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:07.455Z 08DCDDB9DCAC043D]"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0098.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:07.455Z 08DCDDB9DCAC043D]

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0098.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:07.455Z 08DCDDB9DCAC043D]

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: closed
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: opened
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "220 LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 26 Sep 2024 12:37:06 +0000 [08DCDD9447AA1586]"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 26 Sep 2024 12:37:06 +0000 [08DCDD9447AA1586]

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.theproductnumber.com

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.theproductnumber.com

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-LO2P265CA0111.outlook.office365.com Hello [5.134.13.32]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Requested auth method not available: 
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Auth method selected: LOGIN
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: aW5mb0B0aGVwcm9kdWN0bnVtYmVyLmNvbQ==

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6

2024-09-26T12:37:07+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: VzNsbDYyNjYwIyE/

2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0111.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:12.610Z 08DCDD9447AA1586]"
2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0111.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:12.610Z 08DCDD9447AA1586]

2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [LO2P265CA0111.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2024-09-26T12:37:12.610Z 08DCDD9447AA1586]

2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel

2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: Connection: closed
2024-09-26T12:37:12+00:00   ERROR 62.31.39.161  mail    Error in Mail API: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.


I'm sure you know this but PHPmailer can be problematic, are you able to set up a smtp account for the website? If not, give https://www.mail-tester.com/ a go and post back. Is it a particular email provider that doesn't seem to receive the emails? I'd suggest checking if the domain is blacklisted also - https://dnschecker.org/ip-blacklist-checker.php

In my experience anyone with a hotmail.com, outlook.com, live.com or any of the accounts hosted with Microsoft, e.g. MS 365 will not receive anything when PHPMailer is used to send the emails. In particular user registration type emails from a Forum or the like are silently dropped so neither you nor the recipient get any type of notification.

To add to the previous replies: the PHP Mailer and Sendmail methods do not add a DKIM signature to your outgoing emails. With SMTP you can add a DKIM signature but that needs to be configured correctly on the SMTP server (and added to your DNS). I recommend to use SMTP and create a dedicated email account "website@example.com" for your outgoing website emails.
